# php regex get stuff in side comment

Tags: php, regex

```
<?php
$test = "<!--my comment goes here--> Hello World ";
echo  preg_replace('/\<.*?\>/','',$test);
?>
```

the code above echos hello world
i want it to echo *my comment goes here*

Comment: Since this is the syntax of a comment in html are you by any chance parsing an html document?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `preg_match` instead:

```
preg_match('/\<!--(.*?)-->/', $test, $m);
echo $m[1]; // here's your comment
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't preg_match be used for this? you basically want to extract a string, not replace it with another string...